# service apache2 restart didn`t work without any error (also service apache2 reload)

Tags: flask, apache2

I am trying to practice to make website using flask.
So, I was following this video lectures. And I did the same as the lecturer.
But, When typing service apache2 restart or service apache2 reload, I can`t get any error or success meesage. just without any reaction, apache2 is not working. Is there someone who know how to solve this problem?

[image : without any error messages, just stop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFlQJ.png)

(this is the website I was studying from.)
https://pythonprogramming.net/creating-first-flask-web-app/

Comment: Check log files to ensure restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check apache 2 syntax and config with this command

```
apache2ctl -S
```

That command should tell you if you have any syntax errors.
Another thing that you can do is check the logs
the common route for apache logs is `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, so you should check that out as well